# How to embed an image in a PDF using cfpdfform

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, pdf-generation, coldfusion-8

I'm dynamically generating a PDF with a few variables but also need to be able to embed an image on the PDF.  Anyone have any experience doing this using ?

Comment: Are you using cfpdf or cfpdfform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a regular HTML image tag.

However for good print quality images you need to use an image that has larger dimensions than you might use in the document.

For example:

```
<img src="/path/to/my_picture.1280x800.jpg" style="width:320px;height:200px;" />
```

So in that example the width/height of the image file is at 4x what is displayed (obviously the source image need to have that quality to start with; resizing a smaller image bigger wont do much).

Being PDF, you've got conventional units too, so you can use CSS's `in` or `cm` units to set sizes relative to the paper size, but you'll still have the same issue of needing a larger input file. (This example is 160 px:in resolution)

```
<img src="/path/to/my_picture.1280x800.jpg" style="width:8in;height:5in;" />
```

Something else to be aware of - since the images are embedded (uncompressed?) in the PDF this can significantly increase filesizes, so you may need to experiment to work out the best trade-off between filesize and image quality.

Comment: Wrong answer. JGrimm is asking about cfpdfform tag.

Answer (score 1):

Direct html tag did not work. But I figured out a solution which did.

```
<cfset photoLink = "D:\........\example.jpg"> 
<cffile action="readbinary" file="#photoLink#" variable="binAgentPhotoFile"> 
<cfinvokeargument name="photoFile" value="#toBase64(binAgentPhotoFile)#"/>
```

Argument is then passed to the schema.

Comment: JGrimm can you tell us what kind of field do you use to embeed base64. I have Acrobat XI pro and i can see (texfields, buttons, radios) as fillable elements.. but nothing seems to hold as an image container. Can you share with us?

Comment: I have the same problem as Oscar. Everything works in my form except that I cannot find an image field. I'm now trying to make a HTML form element for a base64 image